# Gradle - Creating a fat JAR for a Groovy application

Tags: groovy, jar, gradle

I have a Groovy application that is built with Gradle. I can run it correctly with `gradle run`, but I would like to create a fat JAR to make deployment easier. I have added the instructions

```
jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

to my `build.gradle`.

It seems that a JAR including a lot of dependencied is generated, but when I try to run it with `java -jar myproject.jar`, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.loadReflector(MetaClassImpl.java:1652)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.generateReflector(MetaClassImpl.java:1615)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.checkInitialised(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:140)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addNewStaticMethodsFrom(MetaClassImpl.java:1300)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addInheritedMethods(MetaClassImpl.java:201)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.checkInitialised(MetaClassImpl.java:1529)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry.checkInitialised(MetaClassRegistry.java:201)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry.<init>(MetaClassRegistry.java:113)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry.<init>(MetaClassRegistry.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.Invoker.<init>(Invoker.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToBoolean(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.booleanUnbox(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:65)
    at mycompany.myproject.Main.main(Main.groovy:6)
```

**More details, if they can help**

For reference, here is the full `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

project.group = 'mycompany.myproject'
archivesBaseName = 'myproject'
project.version = '0.1'
manifest.mainAttributes('Main-Class' : 'mycompany.myproject.Main')

apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'mycompany.myproject.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    apply from: 'https://github.com/valkolovos/gradle_cobertura/raw/master/repo/gradle_cobertura/gradle_cobertura/1.2/coberturainit.gradle'
}

jar {
    dependsOn configurations.runtime
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'commons-cli', name: 'commons-cli', version: '1.0'
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.0'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.9'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.5.2'
    compile group: 'groovy', name: 'groovy-xmlrpc', version: '0.3'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.0'
}


run {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split('\\s+')
    }
}

cobertura {
    coverageSourceDirs = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs + sourceSets.main.groovy.srcDirs
}
```

The source of the `Main` class, where the error seems to reside, is

```
package mycompany.myproject


class Main {
    static main(args) {
        def env = args ? args[0] : 'prod'
        new Coordinator().run(env)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen the [fatjar section in the Gradle cookbook](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRADLE/Cookbook#Cookbook-Creatingafatjar)?

Comment: Yes, this is where I got the lines that I mentioned first. In fact it seems that I actually get a JAR with a lot of dependencies in it, but possibly not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the wrong ASM version gets included, although I'm not sure why. Anyway, it's usually simpler and safer to use `groovy-all` instead of `groovy`, and it should also solve this problem.

You shouldn't use Groovy 1.8.0 but the latest minor release (1.8.6).

Comment: Following both your suggestions, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.getCategoryNameUsage(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger;at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.<init>(AbstractCallSite.java:46)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.<init>(CallSiteArray.java:35)
`

Comment: First, remove everything but `groovy-all` from the `groovy` configuration. Have you checked if (version 0.3 of) `groovy-xmlrpc` is compatible with Groovy 1.8? I'd try with the latest version (0.8).

Comment: I removed the other groovy entry (commons-cli) but it made no difference. I surely hope `groovy-xmlrpc` is compatible, since I can test and run the application correctly! The only thing I am not able to do is deploying a single jar.

Comment: `groovy-xmlrpc` 0.3 is very old. Judging from the POM, 0.8 is the best version to use together with Groovy 1.8. Another problem is that `http-builder` will pull in an old Groovy version. You'll have to exclude `groovy`.

Comment: I cannot find it on maven central: `http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22groovy%22%20AND%20a%3A%22groovy-xmlrpc%22`

Comment: Thank you, it has changed group in the meantime! It is now under `org.codehaus.groovy`. With this version, it seems to run :-)